# customize actionbar with different background color - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to style the Actionbar of my app. Since i need to customize more i have replaced the actual ActionBar with ToolBar. I want to design the ActionBar as shown in the below **image1**.

[image]

Below is the toolbar code i am using to customize.

custom_actionbar_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</RelativeLayout
```

activity_toolbar.java

```
 // Custom actionbar starts here
    Toolbar action = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);    
    action.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_scrollable_tabs);    
    action.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ct_drawer);
```

I am getting the action bar like below **image2**,

[image]

1) The problem i am facing is i am not getting the Navigation icon and menu icon as same as requested by the client.

2) How to achieve this using toolbar. Please provide if any other alternate way to achieve this in android.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Set the colorPrimary value of your theme for your style in styles.xml

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

Then define your color in colors.xml file like follows

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
```

Please see this example of setting primary colors 
http://www.dilan.me/articles/tech-notes/android-tips-2-how-to-change-the-main-colors-of-your-app/

Comment: Good, how to have the Navigation Icon and Menu Icon look similar to be like my first  image (i.e image1). I want to have  background color of Navigation Icon and Menu Icon should fills the top and bottom area of toolbar. How to do this.

Comment: you need to create those icon and add them as menu items, if you are using Navigation Drawer you can use its icon for the leftmost one

Answer (score 0):

you can override color in `/res/values/colors.xmal`
and change value of colorPrimary

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
```

or 
use this code

```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

or

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:background="@android:color/black"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                    />
```

Comment: How to have the Navigation Icon and Menu Icon look similar to be like my first  image (i.e image1). I want to have  background color of Navigation Icon and Menu Icon should fills the top and bottom area of toolbar. How to do this.

Comment: you can use an icon that have background and set it for navigation like this
//toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_good);

Comment: I already did that, but the navigation icon is not filling the Top and Bottom portion of toolbar, please see image2 in question and i need it to be like image1. Please help me.